# What approach should be for open voting system

Tags: php, user-experience, rating-system

I am working on a website that has car profiles. There is also rating involved for each profile. Now is there is any good approach to have authentic voting system without making user register?

for example.

there is a profile named `350Z Nissan`. Now users would be allowed to rate it. How can I *avoid Fake rating*?

I thought that I should save IP address along with rating but what if there is single computer at home and many people use it?

What would you do ?

Comment: Please use the search. This question has been asked numerous times in different forms. Checking for the IP is one way to go.

Comment: IP and Cookies are the ways to go for this, I recommend IP Addresses

Comment: @sandeep what if you have 5 family members using same computer?if you puntch same ip  only one can vote

Comment: @rafay use IP Adress and Cookies, check if the system has both the IP Address and Cookie, if not then add the cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are good steps to start:

- One vote per 3/4/6/12/24 (your choice) hours per one ip for non registered users
- Captcha for non registered users (prevents bots)
- Limit number of registrations per day from one ip
- Log every vote

You probably can't do anything more, you may also use cookies and create `pseudousers` (it'll filter out "lame users") but it's easy to work around.

Answer (score 1):

four things

1. use captcha
2. log every visit with all needed data
3. to be more prcise - use email validation ( i mean real email-address validation with mail-server - so they cant use fake emails  --- there are methods available for that ) +  one email can not rate same product twice.
4. do not limit rate per pc or ip... above three should be enough to avoid fake ratings

I think all covered in above - let me know if I am missing something..